# Open popup with linkbutton

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, href, linkbutton

I am using bootstrap modal popup, and this `div` is (FOR EXAMPLE) a popup [using a repeater]

```
<div id="messageContent">Hello World!</div>
```

This pop-up can be opened by doing this (this works):

```
<a href="#messageContent" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Open Popup</a>
```

But I want to pass some `DataBinder.Eval`-values with the `<a href=""></a>`, and this is not possible, so this is what I tried with a `linkbutton`:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbOpenMessage" runat="server" CommandName="OpenMessage" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MessageID")%>'>Open Popup</asp:LinkButton>
```

But I am not abled to call the `<a href="#messageContent"></a>` in the linkbutton to open the pop-up.

When I do something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbOpenMessage" runat="server" CommandName="OpenMessage" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MessageID")%>'>
<a href="#messageContent" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Open Popup</a>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then the `e.Commandname`-event doesn't get fired, so I don't get the MessageID.

What can I do to open the pop-up with `<a href="#messageContent"></a>`, with passing the `DataBinder.Eval`-values?

I did some research, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the modal via a javascript call as opposed to the markup shortcuts. refer here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

the function you want to call is $('#myModal').modal(options)

So in your item command event you want the following:

```
if (e.commandname == "yourcommandname")
{
    // do your stuff that needs to be done
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "key", " $('#myModal').modal(options);", true);
}
```